# Starting the service admin svcadm, does not generate the pid file in /var/run. How is this file created?

Tags: solaris, administration

I have been trying to write a script to start/stop a service with svcadm. But what I do not understand is how do I get the pid of the process executed into /var/run/myprocess.pid? What is not clear to me is that I can not find anything on other scripts in /lib/svc/method that writes to /var/run. Does this mean that I have to explicitly extract the target location of the pidfile from an environment variable, let my program query for itself and write code to put the pid in the /var/run/myprocess.pid file?

Answer (score 1):

The pid file is to be created by the daemon binary itself, not by service scripts. If your code need to be portable to non Solaris 10+ OSes, you might use defines like this:
http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/amd/ibs-gate/usr/src/cmd/ipf/tools/ipmon.c#130